# Function does not take value from form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a form taking several values. One of them is the birthdate which is first taken in date-time. I want to change it into an age. The function works since I have tested it using dummy date time like `"10/10/1980"`. But if I want to calculate with my value of the form which is `this.f.birthdate.value` it just logs

> undefined

`this.f.birthdate.value` actually also works when I log the whole form. It logs the date time there, so I don't get why its undefined.

page.html

```
<form>
...
 <ion-item class="input-item">
     <ion-label>Date of Birth</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime  display-format="DD/MM/YYYY" picker-format="DD MMMM YYYY" formControlName="birthdate" required></ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>


    <ion-button 
    type="submit"
    (click)="calculateAge()"
    [disabled]="!signupForm.valid"
  > Sign Up </ion-button>
</form>
```

page.ts

```
    public birthday: string;
      public age: number;

...

      ngOnInit() {
      this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
        'birthdate': new FormControl(Validators.required)
      });

      }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { 
    console.log(this)
    return this.signupForm.value; 
    } // value or controls

  public calculateAge(): void { // birthday is a date
    this.birthday = this.f.birthdate.value;
    if (this.birthday) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - new Date(this.birthday).getTime());
      this.age = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24) / 365.25);
      console.log(this.age);
          }


  }

submit() {
this.authService.apiSignup(this.f.username.value,
   this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value, this.age, this.f.gender.value)
...
}
```

Comment: f is the value of form. So f.birthday is what you're looking for. Same for f.email or f.password

Answer (score 0):

You need to add formGroup directive inside your form tag and bind it with your reactive form:

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm">
...
 <ion-item class="input-item">
     <ion-label>Date of Birth</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime  display-format="DD/MM/YYYY" picker-format="DD MMMM YYYY" formControlName="birthdate" required></ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>


    <ion-button 
    type="submit"
    (click)="calculateAge()"
    [disabled]="!signupForm.valid"
  > Sign Up </ion-button>
</form>
```